# Jenkins: How to read jenkins credential parameter as a username:password from a build step usin shell script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins Freestyle project.
I am passing build-parameters one of which being credentials-parameter (**nexus_credentials**).
I need to use the `curl` command with `-u` option which will have **username:password** extracted from the parameter passed while running the build.
I tried:

```
curl --fail -u ${nexus_credentials} --upload-file "{$zipefile,$zipfile.md5,$zipfile.sha1,$zipfile.sha256,$zipfile.sha512}" "${nexus_snapshot}${version}-SNAPSHOT/"
```

but in logs I can see its asking for password, and not obtaining, its giving error, **Malformed curl command**.

I also tried to add one more build-step using groovy script to use:

```
withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: '${params.nexus_credentials}', variable: 'USERPASS')]) {
    sh 'curl --fail -u ${USERPASS} --upload-file "{\$zipefile,\$zipfile.md5,\$zipfile.sha1,\$zipfile.sha256,\$zipfile.sha512}" ${params.nexus_snapshot}\$version-SNAPSHOT/'
}
```

But this one gives error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson10594635387748485133.usernameColonPassword() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[credentialsId:${params.nexus_credentials}, variable:USERPASS]]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson10594635387748485133.usernameColonPassword() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[credentialsId:${params.nexus_credentials}, variable:USERPASS]]
    at hudson10594635387748485133.run(hudson10594635387748485133.groovy:1)
Build step 'Execute Groovy script' marked build as failure
```

How should I obtain the username and password ?

Answer (score 0):

try in the first command

```
curl --fail -u ${nexus_credentials_USR}:${nexus_credentials_PSW} --upload-file ...
```

Comment: it didnt work. the parameter `-u ${nexus_credentials_USR}:${nexus_credentials_PSW}` is appearing blank in the logs: `curl --fail -u : --upload-file  ...`